# Is there a way to join specific features of 2 seperate line layers into 1 new layer?

Tags: qgis, vector

Specifically, I am looking to put speed limits (which currently reside in my road network layer), into my bus route layer (which follows some of the same roads, but not all within the road network). The merging vector layer option could be useful (once I manually filter the results in excel), but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Do the features on both layers overlap? if so, you can simply run `join attributes by location`.

Comment: you can try the NNJOIN Plugin, which is very usefull. I've also used it to merge information from OSM Buslines to more pricise CAD based buslines.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.